# Independent parameters for the model of axion-like particle

Tags: cosmology, axion

Consider the following model of an axion-like particle $a$ (or ALP):

$$
\mathcal{L} = (\partial_{\mu}a)^{2}/2 - m_{a}^{2}a^{2}/2 + ag_{a\gamma\gamma}F_{\mu\nu}\tilde{F}^{\mu\nu},
$$
where $F_{\mu\nu}$ is the EM field strength. $m_{a}$ and $g_{a\gamma\gamma}$ are independent constants. My question is the following. The cosmological population of light ALPs ($m_{a}\ll 1\text{ eV}$) that are not ruled out by current experiments is determined by the misalignment mechanism. The latter is determined by the initial amplitude $a_{0}$ of the massless ALP field, which then starts to oscillate once the mass is turned on.

In the QCD axion model, $a_{0}\simeq \alpha_{EM}g_{a\gamma\gamma}^{-1}$. Can we, however, assume that $a_{0}$ is independent on $g_{a\gamma\gamma}$ in the general case of ALPs?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The axion is an angular degree of freedom
$$ \theta \equiv \frac{a}{f_a}\,,$$
where $f_a$ is the axion decay constant. In particular, the axion parent field $\phi = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}\rho e^{{\rm i} \theta}$ acquires a radial VEV $\rho = f_a$.
In the misalignment mechanism, the angular degree of freedom is assumed to have a flat distribution on the interval $[0,2\pi]$ before inflation, hence $\theta$ is assumed to be order $1$ after inflation. Hence $\theta_0 \approx 1\implies a_0 \approx f_a$. The definition of $g_{a\gamma\gamma}$ is $\mathscr{O}(1)\alpha_\text{EM}/f_a$, so your choice of $a_0 = \alpha_\text{EM} g_{a\gamma\gamma}$ is equivalent to the statement that $\theta\sim 1$. Larger or smaller misalignment angles have been considered in the literature, but they are typically a result of fine tuning.

Comment: Thanks. However, in the general ALP model, isn't it the case that $g_{a\gamma\gamma}$ will significantly differ from $\alpha_{\text{EM}}/f_{a}$?

Comment: There are models that have large $g_{a\gamma\gamma}$, called photophilic axions https://arxiv.org/pdf/1611.09855.pdf and small $g_{a\gamma\gamma}$, called photophobic axions https://d-nb.info/1170745687/34. So yes, you can change the relationship between $g_{a\gamma\gamma}$ and $a_0$, but it's best to think of the initial misalignment angle in terms of $f_a$ only, since this is the physical parameter that controls the scale of the axion.

Comment: Am I right that if the ALP appears before the end of inflation, then the misalignment angle may be really arbitrary, whereas if it appears after, then we need to average over causally disconnected patches, and most likely the average of $\theta_{0}^{2}$ is $\simeq 1$?

Comment: Yeah - if PQ symmetry is restored during inflation, then the phase in different Hubble volumes will be a flat distribution in the interval $[0,2\pi]$. If PQ symmetry is broken during inflation, then our Hubble patch (the part of the universe that was in causal contact before inflation) should have similar $\theta_0$.